# Button to check if the movieclip's COLORS match [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm doing a project which for now it's about coloring shapes, the user will have to pick the color and click on the shapes to apply the color and they may click a button to check if it's correct. I manage to do all these but not the button. How do i write the IF/Else or Switch/Case statement for the "check1_btn" button which im going to click to check if the movieclip's colors match the color i pick and if it is matched, it will trace "good" else it will just trace "oops!"

This is the codes for selecting and dropping the colors :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var SelColor:Number = 0xEFEFEF;

// Select Color

redpick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,RedS);
function RedS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0xE14938;
}

orangepick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,OrangeS);
function OrangeS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0xFBA026;
}

purplepick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,PurpleS);
function PurpleS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0x553982;
}

greenpick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,GreenS);
function GreenS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0x61BD6D;
}

bluepick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,BlueS);
function BlueS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0x2C82C9;
}

yellowpick_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,YellowS);
function YellowS (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SelColor = 0xFAC51C;
}

// Fill Color

bigdrop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bdrop);
meddrop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mdrop);
smalldrop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sdrop);

function bdrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var DrawCol = new ColorTransform ();
    DrawCol.color = SelColor;
    bigdrop_mc.transform.colorTransform = DrawCol;
}

function mdrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var DrawCol = new ColorTransform ();
    DrawCol.color = SelColor;
    meddrop_mc.transform.colorTransform = DrawCol;
}

function sdrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var DrawCol = new ColorTransform ();
    DrawCol.color = SelColor;
    smalldrop_mc.transform.colorTransform = DrawCol;
}
```

This is what i'm trying to do, but failed lol :

```
check1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if  (
        bigdrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0x61BD6D;

        meddrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0xFAC51C;

        smalldrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0xE14938;)
    {

        trace("Good");

    }   
    else 
    {
        trace("Oops..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Before speaking code, let's understand what do you want. You are selecting one color and checking 3 objects to show a "Good" or "Oops.." message, but what's your condition to show that message (I'm speaking about your logic not your code) ?

Comment: using semi-colons inside a if statement cannot work. in fact you should start by asking why you are getting so many errors everywhere. After that is fixed, using '=' in a if statement cannot work since it's an assignment, not an evaluator. Finally passing color as Hex is usual but color retrieved are never in that format so they can't be equal to a Hex format.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this:
Replace your if (...) code.

```
 if  (bigdrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0x61BD6D; meddrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0xFAC51C; malldrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color = 0xE14938; )
```

Should be this:

```
if  (bigdrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color == 0x61BD6D && meddrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color == 0xFAC51C &&  malldrop_mc.transform.colorTransform.color == 0xE14938 )
```

What this will do is check all those colors and see if they are correct. The `&&` symbol is an 'and' symbol and essentially means that both the statement before it and after it must be met. Use `==` to compare two values.